# Incrementing an SQL field with rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite

This is probably very easy to solve, but I am having problems updating an SQL field in Android: the following query does not contain any syntax errors but when I run the app, it crashes:

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ FIELD_TO_UPDATE + " = " + FIELD_TO_UPDATE + 1, null);
```

This is the logcat:

```
01-08 16:45:01.269: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 16:45:01.269: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: smsSent1: , while compiling: UPDATE users SET smsSent = smsSent1
```

Basically, the last `+1` is seen as a concatenation and not as a sum, how can I use the `+` operator to increment the `SMS_SENT` field?

Comment: Can you post a logcat or stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ FIELD_TO_UPDATE + " = " + FIELD_TO_UPDATE + "+1", null);
```